Style group of values different in a raster dataset in GeoServer-SLD
I have a GeoTIFF raster with different "parts" of values that should be displayed.
One part is the typical span of values that should be displayed in a color ramp (0 to 4000).
The other is certain value (-9999) that should be displayed separately outside the ramp as it has a special meaning (special area).
So the goal is kind of to have different RasterSymbolizer for a raster within the same style.
If I try to accomplish this with serveral rules like its done for vector data, only the first one seems to be applyed/executed.
Is there a way to style different groups of values in different ways in raster datasets?
<sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <sld:Name>Nordsee_Ausbauszenarien_Volllaststunden_Volllaststunden</sld:Name>
        <sld:Rule>
        <sld:Title>Externe Gebiete</sld:Title>
          <ogc:Filter>
            
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>AUSBAUSZENARIO_S20_H_A</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>-9999</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            
          </ogc:Filter>
          <sld:RasterSymbolizer>
            <sld:ColorMap type="values">
              <sld:ColorMapEntry color="#000000" quantity="-9999" label="External"/>
            </sld:ColorMap>
            <sld:ContrastEnhancement/>
          </sld:RasterSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
        <sld:Rule>
        <sld:Title>Vollaststunden</sld:Title>
          <ogc:Filter>
            
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>AUSBAUSZENARIO_S20_H_A</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
            
          </ogc:Filter>
          <sld:RasterSymbolizer>
            <sld:ColorMap type="ramp">
              <sld:ColorMapEntry color="#fff5eb" quantity="0" label="0,0000"/>
              <sld:ColorMapEntry color="#fdd2a5" quantity="1000" label="1000,00"/>
              <sld:ColorMapEntry color="#fd9243" quantity="2000" label="2000,00"/>
              <sld:ColorMapEntry color="#df5005" quantity="3000" label="3000,00"/>
              <sld:ColorMapEntry color="#7f2704" quantity="4000" label="4000,00"/>
            </sld:ColorMap>
            <sld:ContrastEnhancement/>
          </sld:RasterSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
      </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>


I'm not really sure what happens when you apply a filter to a raster - it is technically allowed by the specification, I'm just not sure that what should happen is defined. Filters are designed to work with the attributes of a Feature while rasters don't have attributes.
I think that what you need is to set the <sld:ColorMapEntry color="#000000" quantity="-9999" label="External"/> in the other ColorMap.

That's what I feared.
I wanted to devide the information to clarify that the -9999 are  artifical values that should not be displayed in the same ramp.
But then, it can't be helped :)
